# After starting Galaxybase, I can access the 51314 page but not the 8888 page

Tags: graph-databases

According to the official documentation, after a successful installation of Galaxybase, I should be able to open the visualization platform by directly entering the current deployed Public IP address in the browser address bar ("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8888/"). However, I can only access the 51314 page and not the 8888 page. Why is that and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't manually made any changes during the installation process, accessing the 8888 page requires first starting the cluster and enabling the "Data Visualization Service" in the service column on the 51314 page. Additionally, ensure that the network is accessible, such as opening the corresponding ports in the firewall.